# Django notification get date one accesses a link

Tags: django, date, notifications

i'm making a notification system, so that a user in a virtual community to be announced when someone sends him a message, or starts following him (the follow relation is like a friend relation, but it is not necessarily reciprocal)

my view function:

```
def notification_view(request, last_checked):
    u = Relation.objects.filter(date_follow>Notification.objects.get(last_checked=last_checked)) 
    v = Message.objects.filter(date>Notification.objects.get(last_checked=last_checked)) 
    x = NotificationSettings.filter(user = request.user)
    notice_settings = Notification.objects.get(notice_type = x) 

    return render_to_response('notification/notification.html', {
        'u': u,
        'v':v,
        'x':x,
        'notice_settings':notice_settings,  

        }, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the models.py:

```
class NoticeType(models.Model):
    follow = models.ForeignKey(Relations, editable = False)     
    message = models.ForeignKey(Messages)
    classroom_invitation = models.ForeignKey(Classroom)

class Notification(models.Model):

    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable = False)
    notice_type = models.ForeignKey(NoticeType, editable = False, related_name = "notification_type") 
    sent = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    last_checked = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable = False)



class NotificationSettings(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     receive_notifications = models.BooleanField(default = True)
     only_follow = models.BooleanField(default = False)
     only_message = models.BooleanField(default = False)
     only_classroom = models.BooleanField(default = False)
     #receive_on_email = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

my problem is:

i want last_checked to be the time when someone acceses a link (the notification link). How can i possibily save that time? how can i get it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

notification.last_checked = datetime.now()
notification.save()
```

put that in the view for your link, and make sure that notification contains your Notification object!